# resampling .agg/.apply behavior

Tags: python, pandas

This question relates to resample `.agg/.apply` which behaves differently than groupby `.agg/.apply`.

Here is an example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(0,100),'B':range(0,200,2)},index=pd.date_range('1/1/2022',periods=100,freq='D'))
```

Output:

```
             A    B
2022-01-01   0    0
2022-01-02   1    2
2022-01-03   2    4
2022-01-04   3    6
2022-01-05   4    8
...         ..  ...
2022-04-06  95  190
2022-04-07  96  192
2022-04-08  97  194
2022-04-09  98  196
2022-04-10  99  198
```

My question is, what does `x` represent in the apply function below. There are times where it behaves as a series and other times it behaves as a df. By calling `type(x)` it returns `df`. However, the below returns an error saying `"No axis named 1 for object type Series"`

```
df.resample('M').apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
```

But this does not. There is no stack for a series, so this would imply `x` represents a `df`.

```
df.resample('M').apply(lambda x: x.stack())
```

Also, when you run `df.resample('M').apply(lambda x: print(type(x)))` the outputs are series, but `df.resample('M').apply(lambda x: type(x))` outputs dataframe type.

So my main question is, what gets passed into apply for `resample`. a `series` or a `dataframe`?

Comment: I've always found the docs unclear/incomplete about this. For me both agg and apply pass a Series for each 'group' for each column in this case (pandas 1.5.2)

Comment: Thats a good point, i wasnt running 1.5.2, but just upgraded and am seeing the same thing. I added a little more to my question which shows the relationship between calling `print(type(x))` and `type(x)`.

Comment: Very interesting, I can't explain that behavior, no idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a really good question and I think I have not the right answer but.

1. `resample` a timeseries returns a `DatetimeIndexResampler` instance.
2. `apply` is an alias of `aggregate` function.

Now check the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8dab54d6573f7186ff0c3b6364d5e4dd635ff3e7/pandas/core/resample.py#L343-L361):

```
    @doc(
        _shared_docs["aggregate"],
        see_also=_agg_see_also_doc,
        examples=_agg_examples_doc,
        klass="DataFrame",
        axis="",
    )
    def aggregate(self, func=None, *args, **kwargs):


        result = ResamplerWindowApply(self, func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).agg()
        if result is None:
            how = func
            result = self._groupby_and_aggregate(how, *args, **kwargs)


        result = self._apply_loffset(result)
        return result


    agg = aggregate
    apply = aggregate
```

What I understand: I think if something goes wrong with `ResamplerWindowApply`, `aggregate` function have a fallback mechanism to reevaluate the function with [`_groupby_and_aggregate`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8dab54d6573f7186ff0c3b6364d5e4dd635ff3e7/pandas/core/resample.py#L428-L475).

The docstring of the last one is :

```
"""
Re-evaluate the obj with a groupby aggregation.
"""
```

Let's debug with a named function:

```
import inspect

def f(x):
    print(inspect.stack()[2].function)
    print(f'begin: {type(x)}')
    x.stack()
    print(f'end: {type(x)}')
    return x.sum(axis=1)

df.resample('M').apply(f)
```

Output:

```
_aggregate_series_pure_python
begin: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>  # something goes wrong
_python_apply_general  # the caller has changed
begin: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  # now x is a DataFrame
end: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
_python_apply_general
begin: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
end: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
_python_apply_general
begin: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
end: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
_python_apply_general
begin: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
end: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

After a failure with a `Series`, `aggregate` calls the function with a `DataFrame`. Unfortunately, this behavior is not documented.

Comment: this is very interesting... do you think I should raise this as an issue on github?

Comment: I don't think so. The behavior is probably what developers really want to do :-)

Comment: @rhug123. I updated my answer using the `inspect` module to know the caller function.